# undefined method `each' for #<UserProfile:0x007fc0d4d1d250>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I encounter undefined method 'each' when I try to display the data in my @user_profile variable. I don't why didn't work. I already searched for some similar problem but nothing happen.

show.html.erb (sample)

```
<% @user_profile.each do |profile| %>

    <p><%= profile.user_id %></p>
    <p><%= profile.firstname %></p>
    <p><%= profile.lastname %></p>

<% end %>
```

UserProfileCOntroller

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @user_profile = @user.user_profile
end
```

I have a 1 to 1 relationship in this .. I don't know why I can't iterate the data inside the instance variable @user_profile but when I try to query using the rails c there is a data inside.

Thank you!

Comment: Can we see where @user_profile is being instantiated? I'm assuming you're getting this error because it's a single instance of UserProfile and isn't Enumerable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `@user_profile.each` as `@user_profile` is not an array. Try the following:

```
<p><%= @user_profile.user_id %></p>
<p><%= @user_profile.firstname %></p>
<p><%= @user_profile.lastname %></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir for the answer.. I'm new in rails. by the way sir, can i ask some question? how do you implement country-select? what gem do you use for rails 4? I already searched something but I confused for so much gem and some compatibility in rails 4 version.

Comment: Here's a list of [possible gems for country select](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=country+select). It's a good place to look for gems in general.

Answer (score 0):

If a `user` has only one `user_profile`. And each `user_profile` belongs_to only one `user`, then I would change the code like this:

```
# in user model
delegate :firstname, :lastname, :to => :user_profile

# in controller
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end

# in view
<p><%= @user.id %></p>
<p><%= @user.firstname %></p>
<p><%= @user.lastname %></p>
```